# Why does Unix have fork() but not CreateProcess()?

Tags: winapi, unix, exec, fork, createprocess

I do not get why Unix has [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) for creating a new process.  In Win32 API we have [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which creates a new process and loads an executable into its address space, then starts executing from the entry point. However Unix offers fork for creating a new process, and I don't get why would I duplicate my process if I'd like to run another process.

So let me ask these two questions:

1. If `fork()` and then `exec()` is more efficient, why isn't there a function `forkexec(const char *newProc)` since we will call `exec()` after `fork()` almost in every case?
2. If it is not more efficient, why does `fork()` exist at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `fork()` call is sufficient.  It is also more flexible; it allows you to things like adjust the I/O redirection in the child process, rather than complicating the system call to create the process.  With SUID or SGID programs, it allows the child to lose its elevated privileges before executing the other process.

If you want a complex way to create a process, lookup the [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) function.

> ```
> #include <spawn.h>
>
> int posix_spawn(pid_t *restrict pid, const char *restrict path,
>         const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
>         const posix_spawnattr_t *restrict attrp,
>         char *const argv[restrict], char *const envp[restrict]);
>
> int posix_spawnp(pid_t *restrict pid, const char *restrict file,
>           const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
>        const posix_spawnattr_t *restrict attrp,
>        char *const argv[restrict], char *const envp[restrict]);
> ```

The difference is the `posix_spawnp()` does a search on PATH for the executable.

There is a whole set of other functions for handling `posix_spawn_file_actions_t` and `posix_spawnattr_t` types (follow the 'See Also' links at the bottom of the referenced man page).

This is quite a bit more like `CreateProcess()` on Windows.  For the most part, though, using `fork()` followed shortly by `exec()` is simpler.

---

> I don't understand what you mean. The child process code will be written by me, so what is the difference between writing `if (fork() == 0)` and putting this code in the beginning of child's `main()`?

Very often, the code you execute is not written by you, so you can't modify what happens in the beginning of the child's process.  Think of a shell; if the only programs you run from the shell are those you've written, life is going to be very impoverished.

Quite often, the code you execute will be called from many different places.  In particular, think of a shell and a program that will sometimes be executed in a pipeline and sometimes executed without pipes.  The called program cannot tell what I/O redirections and fixups it should do; the calling program knows.

If the calling program is running with elevated privileges (SUID or SGID privileges), it is normal to want to turn those 'off' before running another program.  Relying on the other program to know what to do is ... foolish.

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean. child process code will be written by me so what is the difference between writing if (fork() == 0) and putting this code in the beginning of child's main() ?

Comment: hmm, so you say that it is just easier with fork() - exec() couple to do such things (i/o redirection, taking back privileges, etc..) did i get it correct?

Comment: Yes: compared with contortions required for `posix_spawn()`, it is much simpler to use `fork()` and then have the child perform the actions it needs, before using `exec()`.  Read the rationale for `posix_spawn()`; it is quite enlightening (or, at least, it was to me).  The list of things you can do with `posix_spawn()` is impressive, but it is also more complex than what `fork()` provides.

Answer (score 3):

UNIX-like operating systems (at least newer Linux and BSD kernels) generally have a *very efficient* `fork` implementation -- it is "so cheap" that there are "threaded" implementations based upon it in some languages.

In the end the `forkexec` function is ~n -- for some small value of n -- lines of application code.

I sure wish windows had such a useful `ForkProcess` :(

Happy coding.

---

A cnicutar mentioned, [Copy-On-Write (COW)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) is one strategy used.

Comment: ok but if i will transform the process into another after very efficient fork, isn't it better to create the new process from the beginning? then i dont have to duplicate my own process. this is what i dont get

Comment: @Ali Veli Modern forks don't duplicate the process at all. Look up "copy on write".

Comment: lets say that i will create a new process. c-o-w or not, fork does something right? so i think if i just create a new process, i would not do this something (even if it is only 1 instruction).

Comment: @Ali Veli "It just doesn't matter". Listen to Knuth.

Comment: @pst, I interpret this as you have no answer

Comment: @L.B No. The reason for keeping them separate (as well has a combine method) has been answered elsewhere. My response was to address the "it just doesn't matter". Why introduce a new call to do something that doesn't need to be done? Would you want to make all conforming operating systems (for said standard the call would be part of) have to implement said call? How will it affect what semblance of portability there is? Is this a justified decision? That *is* my answer. No need to invent solutions to problems that don't exist.

Comment: @pst if `forkexec` were a good API, all OS's would implement it. Your answer doesn't say why.

Comment: @cnicutar: it matters, especially in embedded and realtime systems. the fact that launching a new process/thread goes through fork() means that, even with COW, you still allocate memory overoptimistically, hoping that the forked processes won't need this memory but will go into exec()s. Anyway, this assumption means that you must allow overallocation. And also means that you need some OOM Killer (the very reason why the OOM killer exists after all). Then, the problem is that the OOM killer is heuristic and could kill your single-most-important-process and bring down your missile. Bad design.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that is equivalent to forkexec - system

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char command[50];

  strcpy( command, "ls -l" );
  system(command);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `system(3)` passes the command you give it to the shell. While it's often implemented on top of `fork(2)`/`execve(2)`, they're not the same.